# Как найти на странице следующий элемент с таким же атрибутом?

Tags: jquery

Допустим, есть несколько картинок. У них у всех атрибут rel="smth". Они идут не впритык, могут быть в разных таблицах, div'ах и т.д.. Так что .next не прокатит. Как их можно выбирать по очереди?

Comment: попробуй обернуть их в class

Comment: А пример можно? В jQuery достаточно посредственно разбираюсь...

Comment: =) да я только теоретик =) нече не знаю, нече не умею, нече не делаю =) просто класс позволит тебе объединить группу элементов в одну, а айди - отличать их в группе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("[rel = 'smth']") - должен выбрать все объекты у которых атрибут rel=smth
```

Comment: Спасибо, будем попробовывать...

Answer (score 1):

есть ещё способ:

```
$('*').filter('[rel=smth]');
```